# Nested eager loading with constraint groupBy and get just last item of group

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Query with non-functional constrain to demonstrate what is intended

```
public function readSongsVersions() 
{
   $data = Hierarchy::query()
           ->whereNull('parent_id')
           ->with(['children.song' => function ($query)  {
                    $query->groupBy('number')
                          ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                          ->max('id') //this does not work
           }])
           ->get();
   }
```

songs table

```
   id  version  number
   1   AAA     1
   2   BBB     1
   3   CCC     1
   4   DDD     2
   5   EEE     3
   6   FFF     4
   7   GGG     4
```

The goal is to get only the latest version of each song

Song number 1 has 3 versions and de last one is: **id:3** with **version:CCC**

Song number 4 has 2 versions and de last one is: **id:7** with **version:GGG**

Expected songs versions result

```
 CCC
 DDD
 EEE
 GGG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using subqueries to achieve the desired output

```php
//Assuming `child_id` is the foreign key on `songs` table 
//which references primary key `id` on `children` table

public function readSongsVersions()
{
    $data = Hierarchy::query()
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->with([
            'children.songs' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', '=', function($query) {
                    $query->select(DB::raw('MAX(i.id)'))
                        ->from('songs as i')
                        ->whereRaw('i.number = songs.number')
                        ->whereRaw('i.child_id = songs.child_id');
                    });
            }
        ])
        ->get();
}
```

Or if you want to do it without subquery

```php
//Assuming `child_id` is the foreign key on `songs` table 
//which references primary key `id` on `children` table
public function readSongsVersions()
{

    //Get ids of songs which have the highest id for particular number and child_id
    //Means get the id of latest version of song for particular number 
    //within records of songs which belong to a particular children record
    $ids = Song::query()
        ->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) as id'), 'child_id', 'number')
        ->groupBy('child_id', 'number')
        ->get()
        ->pluck('id');

    //Then use these $ids to filter out the songs records
    $data = Hierarchy::query()
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->with([
            'children.songs' => fn($query) => $query->whereIn('id', $ids)
        ])
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Donkarnash. My specific case doesn't have the created_at column, so latest() is not viable.
I've already tried with latestOdMany( ) and ofMany(), but so far I haven't been able to succeed. I think I will really have to use groupBY and orderBy() with limit(1). The problem is that limit(1) only seems to work if orderBy is DESC and in this case, to get the last one to enter the BD it has to be ASC.

Comment: @josei `latest('id')`sorts in descending order based on `id` i.e. `latest('column_name')` sorts by the **column_name** passed as argument in descending order. And to get the last one order has to descending not ascending - latest to oldest is descending & oldest to latest is ascending - right?

Comment: $query->groupBy('number')->oldest('id')->limit('1') returns first item 1 of group,; $query->groupBy('number')->limit('1') returns first item 1 of group;  $query->groupBy('number')->latest('id')->limit('1') return a empty array

Comment: Thanks Donkarnash. Both solutions work fine. Once again, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would work in your case.

```php
$data = Hierarchy::select("version","number")
           ->whereNull('parent_id')
           ->withMax(children.song','id')
           ->get()
           ->toArray();
```

You should have something like song_version_max_id into your array. or similar, use dd($data) to see results.

Comment: I tried it in my case, but it didn't work. thanks for helping

Comment: You are welcome. It is much more elegant @Donkarnash solution.